# How to draw a ribboned helix that is not perfect

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I am new to blender and I am trying to draw an alpha helix for a nice model of a protein. I have attached an example [image: secondary structures] Eventually I wish to make the shapes in the blue and yellow. I am starting with the blue ribbon like structure. I saw blender has a screw tool but it is a perfect spiral. I need something a bit more loose and disordered. Also I want it to bend a bit in a arc.

Does anyone have any tips how to do this?

Comment: Making arrows has an exhaustive list of answers here: Blender
Questions
 
Tags
 
Users
 
Badges
 
Unanswered
 
Ask Question
[What's the fastest and / or craziest way to model an arrow in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100203/whats-the-fastest-and-or-craziest-way-to-model-an-arrow-in-blender)

Comment: This page has a search box at the top where you can search for similar questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=helix or https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=streamers  or https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=ribbon

Comment: @cegaton Those are definitely helpful but the problem is they are pretty ordered. If you look closely at the blue ribbon it is bent and irregular. I have tried the screw function but it is two uniform.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65633/how-can-i-create-twisted-geometry