# 3D Octant cube model from Rubik's Cube 2x2

Tags: modeling

I would like to create a 3D Octant cube, similar to the following image.

[image: Octane model]

In order to do so, started trying to find a 3D model of it but couldn't find any. So, instead, started thinking about similar objects that could be easily adapted into that one. The one I think closely resembles it is a Rubik's Cube 2x2.

Using Sketchfab, was able to find some models of it

- https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/2x2-cube-solve-c2e32d6cc9dd49b7bdd98d04f0c3bb4e
- https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/rubiks-cube-2x2-black-b3579a67f12b4c67ba5cb5b802cd6704

[image: Rubik's Cube 2x2]

Even though the models look very close to the octant I want, it still needs

- the xyz axis,
- transparent cubes with respective text (-, -, -), (-, +, -)
- panels (seen in the first image in purple, blue and orange)

I know how to import models but nothing more than that. My take to solve it would be to search for "how to create axis / make colors transparent / .... in Blender", ... until the solution is pieced together. So, stuck by not knowing the answer to such questions.

I suspect the hardest one for me is to create the panels. How could that be done?

Comment: Hi. What have you tried and where *specifically* in the process of creating this model are you getting stuck?

Comment: Hi @RayMairlot, I see why you ask that. This is a procedure question from someone with little to no experience in Blender; as it's very general, general answers are ok. I know how to import models but nothing more than that. My take to solve it be to search for "how to create axis / make colors transparent / .... in Blender", ... until the solution is pieced together. So, stuck by not knowing the answer to such questions. I expected this was something easy / natural for a Blender user: do this, do that. In general terms it is fine, but can't complain if a more detailed answer is given.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately this site is for *specific* questions and questions that are too broad are considered [off-topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and will likely be closed.

Comment: Isn't this specific to a particular context?

Comment: Hello and welcome Tiago. This site is more geared towards specific questions focused on solving a single issue at a time . Ask only one question per post, make as many as necessary. Could you please edit your question with the information you just posted on the comments focusing on one single issue, so we can reopen it? Also make sure to search thoroughly to ensure none of our existing questions cover your topics.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos would this modification suffice?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100203/whats-the-fastest-and-or-craziest-way-to-model-an-arrow-in-blender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I thought about adapting an already existing 3D model of a Rubik's cube but after speaking with a Blender user, he told me that in order to achieve this I just need to:

> 3 planes, turn 90° each other, subdivide each, assign material, join.
>   Then extrude verts (with Ctrl) and fill.

(so basically he told me to not consider adapting the model because this is something easy)

This was the result he got, which is exactly what I wanted - it misses only the axis and text:

[image: Final result]

With his message, managed to create the planes (by pressing Shift+A and select Plane from the drop-down list and then rotating them (Plane has rotation 0, 0 0; Plane 001 has rotation 90, 0, 0; Plane 002 has rotation 90, 0, 90)), subdivide each (Tab > Right Click > Subdivide once), and assign a color in Material Properties (notice that to see the colors one has to activate Viewport shading). Then, joined the planes and extruded vertices (Editor mode, right click > extrude vertices and use CTRL do get the point fixed in the proper location).

This is the final result:

Object mode:
[image: 3D Octant cube Blender Object mode]

Editor mode:
[image: 3D Octant cube Blender Editor mode]