# How to make a simple plane slightly transparent?

Tags: modeling, transparency

I've got the following Octant Cube and would like to make the planes slightly transparent so that I can see what's behind them.

[image: Blender Octant]

I've gone to Plane > Plane > Color Blue > material section of the Navigation Bar. There, as you can see in the previous image, there's a Surface: Background with a specific color.

Tried in a brute force way changing the Surface to different values other than background and shifting its properties to see if in at least one could get that slight transparency but no success yet.

How to make a simple plane slightly transparent to see the other planes behind?

---

As per Frederik Steinmetz's suggestion, I've created a new material called Transparent and assigned but can't see any difference.

[image: Alpha material]

---

As per Emir's feedback, I've gone to View > Area > Select Vertical Split. On the new new Viewport, went to Editor Type and selected Shader editor. Inside the Shader Editor Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> and Type "Transparent BSDF". <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> Then <kbd>S</kbd> again and now type Mix Shader. ConnectED the Transparent Node to the mixer and also  connected the Principled BSDF, making sure alpha has 0.750. Connected that Mix Shader Node to de output.

[image: Still not working]

Just did gone through the same process again and still didn't get anything transparent

[image: No transparent plane]

---

In order to see if the problem was due to me joining the planes before, created them again and follow the procedure mentioned by Emir but still no success in making it transparent.

[image: Joining wasn't necessarily the problem]

Comment: I don't really dare to post this as an answer, because I feel like I missed something: Click on the use nodes btn, You'll get a bunch of options (principled shader), one of which is Alpha. That's opacity in percent.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz when I click in Use Nodes, it only shows - base color, metalic, specular, roughness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use Transparent Node

-Go to View > Area > Select vertical or Horizontal Split.

-On this new Viewport go to Editor Type and select Shader editor.

-Inside the Shader Editor Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> and Type "Transparent".

-<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> Then <kbd>S</kbd> again and now type Mix Shader.

-Connect your Transparent Node to this mixer and also  connect the Principled 
  BSDF.

-Connect that Mix Shader Node to de output.

** Under the transparent Node Color White is 100% transparent and Black is 0% Transparent.

[image]

If up to this point you don't get transparent plane, go to *Material Properties > Settings > Blend Mode* and change that property to *Alpha Blend*.

Comment: The GIF and the explanation look great, learn many new things. Still, as I shared in the new Question edit, didn't manage to get it with some transparency...

Comment: From your image i'm noticing that your Transparent Node is Black, that means 0 Transparent, you need to change the color to White. This node is not related whit the Alpha input

Comment: Emir I tested different variations of that as you mention («** Under the transparent Node Color White is 100% transparent and Black is 0% Transparent.»). Could it be that I joined the planes? (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/178471/84701)

Comment: Emir just gone through the same process again from the start and it doesn't get transparent (as you can see in the new image with the Transparent BSDF Node in White)

Comment: Just tested to see if the problem was due to joining the planes by creating them again and following this procedure but no success.

Comment: The pricipled shader has its own alpha now, no need for transparent node.

Comment: If it's not working, then you need to remove Blender (all the folders) and install again

Comment: @Emir just removed Blender (with its folders) and installed again. Are you sure you don't have any other configuration in place?

Comment: Nothing, default Blender settings, just that, another option could your graphic card

Comment: @Emir can you send me your file so that I try to open here on my side and see if it opens transparent?

Comment: Here you have it... https://mega.nz/file/qMIiwabY#K1SvY-k9iYX0OTDuoG6G99P2MOdbBBhNK6ZRkEr5bJI

Comment: It shows transparent... Weird that I couldn't get it to work following the steps mentioned.

Comment: @Emir found what was missing and already made an edit to include that info. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Just to be on the safe side: Create a new material, assign it to one of your planes. in the  Shader editor you get:
 
[image]

Adjust the alpha to your likings. 
You should be able to see the same options in the material properties, when you clicked use nodes. You need to be in rendered view to preview any transparency effects. Make sure to check 'use nodes'.
[Big EDIT]
If you want to see the effect in preview: [image]
This way you can't set the transparency per object, just for all.
You will soon be able to use these settings for individual objects in solid view:
[image]

Comment: Just updated the question with my attempt. Nothing changed. Could it be that it's because I joined all the planes?

Comment: You need to be in rendered view to see that

Comment: Updated the image, the problem remains

Comment: My Viewport shading doesn't have the options yours has... Only get Lighting (Selection box with Scene Lights or Scene World) and Render Pass (dropdown with Combined)