# Glass is very black and opaque while rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

I've tried everything I can think of, remade the glass material three different ways, asked many people, but the problem is not fixed yet. Searched on YouTube, Stackexchange and Discord but, none of the solutions work. Attaching image for reference.

[image: seems to work in render preview only]

[image: I have used a simple glass BSDF for this material]

[image: This is the absolute garbage render that I have no idea on how to fix]

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe overlapping faces? If it's not the case please share your file

Comment: Share the file via https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions there.

Comment: Just in case, check your Light-Paths > Transmission (and Total) bounces are high enough, in the render tab..

Comment: @JohnEason I uploaded it, can you see it?

Comment: @RobinBetts Transmission - 12, Total - 16

Comment: @SledgeHammer No we can't. You need to edit your question and paste the link to the file into the question.

Comment: You could add a Transparent with mix shader and make sure to use Alpha Blend Inside the Material settings. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180986/how-to-make-a-simple-plane-slightly-transparent/181003#181003

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the *Caustics* options in the *Render* panel:

[image]

Comment: Thanks moonboots, it worked! I think BlenderGuru said it saves render time...