# How can I make transparent window for cycles and eevee in Blender?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to make windows for this building but I am having trouble finding a good window texture that works well in Cycles and Eevee... This is what the building and texture nodes look like so far:

[image: Building with windows]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a simple plane slightly transparent?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180986/how-to-make-a-simple-plane-slightly-transparent)

Comment: @Emir no, I'm wanting it to be completely transparent but have a bit of gloss, as in the light reflects off like a window... I don't want reflections from objects though...

Answer (score 1):

Glass BSDF should be fine for cycles, although the default IOR (1.45) is best suited for solid thick glass, like a crystal ball, more than a window, so I suggest bring it down a little.

For EEVEE, there are 2 main methods, but with both, it is imperative that you change the materials *Blend Mode* settings to something other than the default *Opaque* (Alpha-Blend works well for most applications). Here are 2 examples of EEVEE "glass" shaders below - one uses a custom node setup, the other uses  the Principled BSDF with the Transmission set to 1 and the Roughness set to 0 (or close to it). They work a bit differently, but perform very similarly.:

[image: BSDF]

OR

[image: Sahders]

Comment: Is there a way I can make the same material work for both? I'm wanting to make it where I can swap between the two...

Comment: Both the "EEVEE" methods I showed, should work fine for both EEVEE and Cycles. Glass BSDF only works (convincingly) in Cycles.

Comment: The IOR of 1.45 is completely fine for windows too, if you create real windowpanes with a thickness of 3 to 4 mm. If you just use a single face plane for this of course it looks terrible.