# What's the fastest / most fun way to create a fork in Blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, shaders

> <sup>Related challenge: [What's the fastest and / or craziest way to
> model an arrow in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/100203/78972)</sup>

I tried to make a fork in Blender, but it was so boring I fell asleep.
Is there a faster / more fun way to make a fork?

I'm open to everything: *Modifiers, shaders, curves, booleans, displacement nodes...*

<sup>I always get only this far, and then <sup>- - - chrrrrrrr - - -</sup></sup>
[image]

Comment: Drink a cup of cofee

Comment: The laziest way would be  post a question on the blender.stackexchange like "I'm new to blender and I need to make a fork ASAP. Plz help"

Comment: @susu There's this 'moonboots' guy he's really good with cutlery

Comment: Can always rely on  some  _"Fork WIt"_  to produce a HNQ

Comment: You shouldn't put a fork in the blender, you'll damage the blades.

Comment: @JachymMichal ... you started something legendary :)

Comment: Lol thanks Jachym.  I appreciate it

Comment: @AllenSimpson When I started this challenge, I hoped someone would attempt a pure node based solution :). I wasn't really sure it was even posssible :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As you know a fork rarely comes with only one peak, it generally has 2, more often 3 or 4, sometimes more. It would be very tedious to model each and every of those peaks.

As you may know, for this kind of task, Blender comes with very powerful tools like *linked duplications, dupliframes, array modifier*, etc... instead of modeling each of the peaks, you can model only one and repeat it infinitely.

Here I've used ***Particle System > Hair***. The huge advantage is that you can easily choose the amount of peaks:

[image]

You can also change the *Seed* value in order to make it look more natural:

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: " *I hope it helps.* " it doesn't much, but at least it was fun :D

Comment: Bless you 'boots. This is gold! :D

Comment: This fork is specially useful for blending!

Comment: thanks, glad it helped

Comment: Why, oh why, didn't I think of that before? _Such_ a time-saver.

Comment: yes a lot of hidden tricks in Blender, it's crazy

Comment: Some folks have **FAR** too much time on their hands! :^)

Comment: Did I miss April Fool's day?

Comment: I joined this exchange just to comment my appreciation of this post. I actually love how this is a good exercise to learn some of the blender concepts. I would love a set of tutorials where the result is always something ridiculous like this lol

Comment: this is a triumph *music starts*

Comment: "more natural" -- this got me. I need a hankie. +1

Comment: "more natural" *fork ominously pointing lots of peaks at me*

Answer (score 38):

IMO the fastest method should be to subdivide a primitive icosphere and use the *Cast* modifier set to *Fork*, but this option is mysteriously missing from Blender!

[image: where is fork]

In my opinion this is bad, and the devs should feel bad.  It's easy enough to represent using the following node group.

[image: wtf]

**Cool, but does it render well?**

Not really.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't feel _so_ bad about the render... the background is quite nice...

Comment: I heard they did Terminator 2 with this node setup

Comment: What in the actual fork!? This is great! :D

Comment: the morphing would need a little tuto

Comment: Is the sphere->fork morph done using Shape Keys?

Comment: Nodevember rules, everything happens in nodes apart from subdiv to give me some geometry.  It's a vector math -> multiply right after the vector displacement, keyframed from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 31):

This is both **fun** and *fast*

```
git clone git://git.blender.org/blender.git
git checkout -b my-fork
```

Comment: Quite frankly, that's just a branch.  I'd go for this instead, which _actually_ forks the repo to your account on GitHub:  `curl -X POST -u "${USER}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}" -d "{\"user\": \"${USER}\"}" "https://api.github.com/repos/blender/blender/forks"`

Answer (score 28):

Another solution would be to use *Softbody*:

[image]

Please tell me if you need a more in detail explanation.

Comment: Yes. Please add detail on how to do the plane

Comment: I've booleaned a dodecahedron, but you can do it with some hardsurface addons

Comment: there's now an addon called Plane but it's 90 $  :((

Answer (score 25):

**Unicode font**

Copy the fork   from [unicode fonts](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_index.html)

Add a font, edit mode, select text, select font, paste fork, extrude.

[image]

Comment: Paying "homage" to my ["best" ever answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/100298/15543).. well vote-wise.

Comment: Was contemplating the ancient history of the fork. The first known fork is thought to have been a wooden mono-prong arrangement, invented by MumbleGrunt _circa_ 49,000 BC.

Answer (score 12):

... **tmp FORK**

- keep default *Cube*
- add *Array* modifier and *Mirror* modifier (be careful about modifiers order)
- add *Curve Constraint* ... but as you can see it's not enough time to enjoy its company ... :)

[image]

Like 3D printer, but much-much-much faster.
But as many other things in our lifes the speed has a cost in its service life.

[image]

Comment: **keep** the default cube?? :O

Comment: must... not... UPVOTE...