# What's the most fun way to make a Snowman in Blender? ❄︎❄︎❄︎

Tags: modeling, particles, shaders, physics, geometry-nodes

> <sup>Previous challenge: [What's the most fun way to create a fork in Blender??](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/207755/78972)</sup>

Winter is here, and I'm trying to build a snowman.
But my Blender freezes after the first snowball! (is it because of the ice?)

There's gotta be a better way!
**How would YOU build a snowman?**

Use shaders, particles, python, geometry nodes, simulations or even your very own kitchen blender.
And please make it fun, I'm a millenial and have a really short attention span :))

[image]

Comment: Damn I missed your happy mood around here

Comment: Bah humbug! Question should be closed as opinion based! :^))

Comment: I wish I were any good with the Molecular addon...

Comment: And this made it to HNQ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's another just for the Geometry Nodes.  :)

[image]

The main part of the body is here:

[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

The idea for the body is to scatter points on the input mesh, and then remesh using the points to volume node. From there, it is simply assembly from instances and curve primitive nodes.

Here is the hat:

[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

In 3.1 the *curve parameter* seems to have been replaced by *spline parameter*.

Here are the rest of the frames that complete the node tree:

[image: nose]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

[image: smile]

<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

[image: buttons]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

[image: eyes]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

[image: ground]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

And this is the complete tree.
[image: complete node tree]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

Here's the file to play with:

[image]

Comment: niiiiiiiiiiiiiice!!! +1

Comment: Had no idea geometry nodes were this advanced :). Thanks for adding the screenshots and explanation, now this answer is genuinely the most useful :)

Answer (score 23):

Let's use collision and cloth (hard I know, but please try to follow!)

Let's make this random thing:
[image]

Add your settings like pressure, friction, stickiness, and eureka!
[image]

Now you have a base for a snowman that only works at frame 58... Oh wait...

Oh no, he is depressed :(((

[image]

Maybe add some snow and he will be happy again ... too much work for me

Comment: love that depressed one.... +1

Comment: Nothing like a depressed snowman with no eyes to make my day brighter!

Comment: eyeballs or limbs are too hard, that's why annotation exists (true facts)

Comment: Congrats for getting the most upvotes on your snowman-building skills :)) +500 points for you, well deserved :))

Comment: I knew that depression can win it xD Thank you so much for this Christmas gift @JachymMichal !

Answer (score 21):

## The Abomitaball Snowman

A glowing abomination straight from Chernobyl.

[image]

Made from a series of metaballs plus a [particle system emitting metaballs from a hidden mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194013/19307)

1. Shape the static part of your snowman with a few metaballs
2. Add a mesh emitter object roughly shaped like your snowman body. You can optionally make it from a copy of your metaball base and convert it to mesh to use as emitter.
3. Add a simple particle system with *Newtonian Physics*, pointing to an additional smaller sized Metaball object.
4. Under *Velocity* turn off *Normal* and increase *Object Z* slightly.
5. In the *Field Weights* disable gravity so they "float up", then add
   a texture to it.

[image]

6. Make the texture is *Blend* type, and turn off all influences except
   *Size*.
7. Switch *Mapping* to *Strand/Particle* so it maps out "through time"
   rather than any spatial coordinate.
8. Under the *Color* panel enable the *Color Ramp* and flip the default
   result direction so they shrink with age rather than grow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: too hard to follow steps

Comment: OK I'll admit - a glowing sublimating snowman was NOT on my bingo card this year :D

Comment: @MikoCG hope it is clearer now

Comment: Yummy meatballs.

Answer (score 21):

Lately I find myself tired with all those mouse clicks to add a sphere, and duplicate it 2 times, it's just so much work... So I just type some code, like this instead:

`C.area.type='VIEW_3D';o=bpy.ops.object;a=D.objects;c=a[1];c.select_set(1);o.shade_smooth();d=o.duplicate;m=c.modifiers.new('','SUBSURF');m.levels=3;d();b=a[2];b.location.z=-1.6;b.scale*=1.5;d();b=a[3];b.location.z-=2;b.scale*=1.5;d();b=a[4];m=b.modifiers.new('','MIRROR');m.mirror_object=c;m.use_axis=0>1,1>0,1<0;m=D.materials[1];m.diffuse_color=[2]*4;m=m.copy();b.active_material=m;b.location=[.5]*3;m.diffuse_color=0,0,0,1;b.scale/=10;[exec('d();b=a[i+5];b.scale=[.1]*3;b.location=Vector((2,sin(i/2),-cos(i/2))).normalized()*.8')for i in range(5)]`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> Copy it, in Blender in a new project (with default cube) press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, done.

As requested by Jachym Michal on behalf of phone users and exceptionally lazy people, an image (click to reveal; please, instead just copy-paste the code once at home):

> it's also a more readable and interactive version: [image]

Comment: Thanks maaaan, now I can have a default creepy snowman instead of a cube :D

Comment: @JachymMichal I thought about it, figured it would spoil a surprise - fortunately there's a spoiler feature on SE!

Comment: @cocomac thanks for edit, I used to write pluses in key combos, but then I saw others on BSE not use them, with the shortcuts still being readable (maybe even more), so I found the pluses redundant. According to a [meta discussion](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/250/60486) both are fine. As for the code formatting change, I reverted it, because unlike usual code it's a very long oneliner, so single backticks make it easier to read and copy to clipboard.

Comment: Nice spoiler free edit ;)

Comment: The best part of this answer is that when you upvote, the tooltip is "This answer is useful"

Answer (score 17):

you've got to pump it up...cloth simulation with pressure

[image]

Comment: and I love how the head pops up at the end :D

Answer (score 14):

Go to pixabay.com -> search for snowman -> download image

Then use this node setup:

[image]

Is this the cheapest and worst solution ever? Yeah

Was this the fastest answer? Yeah

Comment: +1 for the cheapest but definitely fastest answer :))

Comment: cmon man, you could at least give it alpha and cut the black color

Comment: @MikoCG He's waiting for a bounty to do that ;)

Comment: @MikoCG: if i would have done that...it won't be the cheapest anymore... ;)

Comment: Ummmm.. WAY too much work. You could just have drag-and-dropped the image into the workspace.

Comment: @Robin Don't give that man any ideas...

Comment: i could spent money and let someone else do the snowman for me..... :D

Comment: @Chris Yes! .. But I warn you.. I'm expensive.

Comment: @RobinBetts : how much?

Comment: i like where this is going...

Comment: @Chris .. All that dragging-and-dropping doesn't come cheap.

Answer (score 13):

Let's make it hyper realistic

Start with 2 cubes

Switch to front view and change the studio light

[image]

Add relistic arms and hand

[image]

This is the tricky part (face and belly) be careful

[image]

And don't forget the scarf and hat

[image]

Not even ILM can handle this level of detail

Happy Holidays to all :)

Comment: and now turn it around xD

Comment: Love the mittens and scarf, that snowman has class ;)

Comment: I can't really tell if it's a render or a photo at the last one.

Answer (score 11):

Softbody solution with collision:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

_________Under pressure !!!!!!

[image]

Comment: I reversed it to make it look like melting, but didn't turn quite right :) https://imgur.com/FeTRGNP

Comment: Ohh... a bouncy anti stress snowball :)) Perfect!

Answer (score 10):

Here's my lazy way with a few modifiers from the default cube.

[image]

Comment: What a great start to my fully procedural Christmas! :)

Comment: I was thinking about an array solution, but setting it up as modifiers only and using mask and screws instead of to sphere cast for extra roundness is a nice touch. :)

Answer (score 7):

Minimalistic Animation nodes solution:

[image]

If you can use less nodes, let me know. I am happy to learn ...!!

Answer (score 6):

Geometry nodes solution:

[image]

I am sure, it is possible with less nodes. Robin will show us ;)

Comment: You're really covering all the bases with your answers here :D

Comment: Nope - I didn’t provide a shader nodes solution - and no sverchok….and no rigid body…

Answer (score 6):

Maybe... a quote approach... I don't remember if it is from Ton or someone else?

[image]

Comment: I have to show this to my girlfriend. We both love The Little Prince. Thank you Lemon, this is really sweet :)

Comment: @JachymMichal, so... romantic ; )

Comment: i know you too well lemon, you just want to ruin the moment :D

Comment: are you **really** pushing me to talk about cats @JachymMichal ??

Comment: no. just no. not today! this challenge is about snowmen!

Answer (score 6):

Like many things Blender related, the "man" portion of this has already been built and released to the internet under a CC0 license.

Thanks to lsmft - https://www.blendswap.com/blend/8395
[image]

It is then trivial to craft a snow.

[image]

And apply a coat of snow to the base mesh with a *Particle System*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's the gigachad of snowmen ⛄

Answer (score 6):

I decided to make mine with a python script and using the real_snow addon that comes with blender, turned out really well I think.

I'm planning to make this into my first blender addon called "Snowman Generator". I'm just learning to make blender addons right now.

Fun contest, thanks!

[image: snowman]

Comment: cool... you should eventually share you code! +1

Comment: I will throw it on github once its done for sure

Comment: Ummm... Yeah, looks "slightly" better than my Python Snowman... 