# Displaying direction using python

Tags: python

I have created a room in blender using vertices from scratch. It is like a prototype that can be used by other users to build a different model using different vertices. For the convenience of other users I want to display direction (North, South, East, West) on output of any blender model they create. Is it possible to do so using python ?

Comment: How about creating [arrow meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/100203/60486) (please note, the highest voted answer is not always the best answer), perhaps also with addition of Text objects, and disabling them from rendering by setting `hide_render` attribute to `True`?