# Using keyframes to define values in a geometry node (arrow creation)

Tags: geometry-nodes

This [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276576/animate-arrows-along-curves-and-lines-with-multiple-points) explaining how to create arrows using Geometry Nodes is very useful.

I was wondering if it is possible to define start and stop times for the animation of the arrows using keyframe controls, instead of having to adjust values in the Start Frame / End Frame Geometry Nodes?

[image: node setup]

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 0):

Hover mouse cursor at any value in any node and press <kbd>I</kbd> - It will add a key frame as usual.

You can also connect value to group input, in this case you will be able to add keyframes in modifier, so that it will be per object.

Comment: I don't think that works as I imagined for the example (apologies if my explanation isn't clear).  In the example shown, I would like the animation to start (eg) at frame 5 and end at frame 100.  If I add a keyframe to the End Frame Property, that won't show me where the arrow starts and ends on my timeline. example here:  https://imgur.com/a/u8oZhYc

Comment: *End* of *Trim curve* node is from 0 to 1. You can remove time nodes and drive it directly using keyframes.

Comment: @tomh: this is how it looks what Crantisz meant (i believe): [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFjWz.jpg so your keyframes fits to your visible result

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the current setup can easily be extended to achieve the desired goal:

[image]

Here I simply use an additional integer value at the input *From Min* of the node `Map Range`, which controls the trimming of the curve.

Of course you can also provide these two values (*Frame Start* and *Frame End*) via a *Group Input* and control it with keyframes.