# Creating dashed lines along an arrow's tail using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

This [answer on how to programatically create an arrow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276576/animate-arrows-along-curves-and-lines-with-multiple-points) that forms along a curve is very useful.

I would like to know how to convert the arrow's tail into a dashed line, as shown below, but keeping the properties of a geometry node, so the arrow is easily editable.

[image: dashed line extruded]

[image: dashed extruded arrow line]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this node tree (old are muted, new are in the "new" group):

[image]

result:

[image]

and if you move the resample node to here:

[image]

it is smoother ;)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!  If anyone has trouble finding the "Align" node on the screen shot, its full name is "Align Euler to Vector" - it took me a while to spot it.