# Geometry Nodes: how to calculate custom normal deformation?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, normals, geometry, mathematics

GN currently doesn't support Custom Normal input, however you can import them as some other data. Once. If however the mesh is animated, those normals need to get deformed too. It seems that having the mesh and it's true normals should be enough to do that. Any idea what could be the simplest way?

Comment: How are you animating it?  Object transforms, modifiers, or GN?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279041/showing-face-vertex-normals-as-fancy-arrows/279098#279098 has me using some tricks to get custom normals into GN; might be useful for you depending on the specifics.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks! Almost the same - displace along CN->store->displace back). Then the character deforms by Armature etc. Then Subdivision and Displacement along custom Normals for fur. Fur could get fancier if displaced by GN. But I'd have to deform stored CN... untill - I read your comment and it occured to me that I could just grab the normals from the final mesh. Which would be slower (given subdivision). However - actual tests show <3% performance difference in grabbing norm befre/after subdivision! Wierd. Furthermore - the whole thing is just 4% slower than Displacement.

Comment: @Nathan ...The bulk of computation seems to be in the SS Modifier.
Not sure how to mark this now though. It is resolved, but the question was on how to compute Normal deformations from Mesh/real-normal deformation...

Comment: You could just leave it open; the question is valid of course, although I'm not sure it's currently answerable; I don't know the general answer off the top of my head and am not inclined to do a bunch of experimentation to figure it out.  I just guessed you had a particular situation that was solvable without solving the general problem.